# GetBoundingBox() values not changing after scale in gazebo (using : visual_plugin)

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo ver: 7.0, ROS : Kinetic
[Posted in ros.answers, closed and told to post here]

Hello,

I am using a visual_plugin to get the box corner points, so later while scaling the object to change the color. I run this plugin inside the box model from the sdf file.

Everything loads good, the box points in the beginning are ok, same as defined in sdf, but if I scale the box (Inside Gazebo), the points when I printout > box_points_, remain the same but if I check in Gazebo into the properties of the box, the points are updated (If I use GetWorldPose(), and printout the pose and move the box, it works, the values are updated). How can I get the boundingbox to update the points in the plugin as I scale.

**TheBox.sdf**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <world name='default'>   
    <model name="TheBox">  
    <pose frame=''>30 13.9 3.05 0 0 0.012944</pose>

    <link name="TheBox">
        <gravity>false</gravity>
        <visual name="visual">
        <transparency>0.5</transparency>
        <geometry>
            <box>
            <size>18 2.9 6</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
            <ambient>1 0 0 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</specular>
            <emissive>0 0 0 0</emissive>
        </material>

        <plugin name="BoxManipulator" filename="libBoxManipulator.so"/>

        </visual>
    </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

**BoxManipulator.cpp**

```
#include "BoxManipulator.h"

void BoxManipulator::Load(gazebo::rendering::VisualPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf) {

    // Store the pointer to the model
    this->world_ = _parent;

    this->scene_ =  gazebo::rendering::get_scene();
    this->box_ = this->scene_->GetVisual("TheBox");

    // Listen to the update event. This event is broadcast every simulation iteration.
    this->update_connection_ = gazebo::event::Events::ConnectPreRender(std::bind(&BoxManipulator::OnUpdate, this));
  }

  // Called by the world update start event
  void BoxManipulator::OnUpdate() {

    // Box model
    gazebo::math::Vector3 box_origin_ = this->box_->GetWorldPose().pos;
    gazebo::math::Quaternion box_orientation_ = this->box_->GetWorldPose().rot;

    //Update the points
    getBoxPoints();

    //Printout the points
    for (int i = 0; i < box_points_.size(); i++) {
      std::cout << "Box corner points  : [" << i << "] - " << box_points_[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    box_points_.clear();

    // //Later So I can change the color of the box, in different scales

    //     ROS_INFO("Box smaller than 1^3");
    //     red_ = 1; green_ = 0;
    //     gazebo::common::Color _color(red_, green_, blue_, alpha_);

    //     this->world_->SetAmbient(_color);
    //     this->world_->SetDiffuse(_color);


  }

  bool BoxManipulator::getBoxPoints(void){
    gazebo::math::Vector3 _buff; box_points_.reserve(8);

    _buff.x = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.x; _buff.y = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.y; _buff.z = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.z;
    box_points_.push_back(_buff);
    _buff.x = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.x; _buff.y = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.y; _buff.z = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.z;
    box_points_.push_back(_buff);
    _buff.x = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.x; _buff.y = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.y; _buff.z = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.z;
    box_points_.push_back(_buff);
    _buff.x = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.x; _buff.y = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.y; _buff.z = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.z;
    box_points_.push_back(_buff);

    _buff.x = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.x; _buff.y = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.y; _buff.z = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.z;
    box_points_.push_back(_buff);
    _buff.x = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.x; _buff.y = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.y; _buff.z = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.z;
    box_points_.push_back(_buff);
    _buff.x = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.x; _buff.y = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.y; _buff.z = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.z;
    box_points_.push_back(_buff);
    _buff.x = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.x; _buff.y = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().min.y; _buff.z = this->box_->GetBoundingBox().max.z;
    box_points_.push_back(_buff);

    return true;
  }

  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_VISUAL_PLUGIN(BoxManipulator)
}
```

**BoxManipulator.h**

```
#ifndef ___BOX_MANIPULATOR___
#define ___BOX_MANIPULATOR___

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/callback_queue.h>

#include <sdf/sdf.hh>

#include <gazebo/math/gzmath.hh>

#include <gazebo/rendering/rendering.hh>


class BoxManipulator : public gazebo::VisualPlugin {
public: 

/// \brief Load the model from the sdf
void Load(gazebo::rendering::VisualPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf);

/// \brief Called by the world update start event
virtual void OnUpdate();

private:

/// \brief Pointer to the model
gazebo::rendering::VisualPtr world_;

/// \brief Variable to store the box model
gazebo::rendering::VisualPtr box_;

/// \brief Pointer to the update event connection
gazebo::event::ConnectionPtr update_connection_;

/// \brief get box points
bool getBoxPoints(void);

/// \brief check
bool check(void);

gazebo::rendering::ScenePtr scene_;

double  red_ = 0,
        green_ = 0,
        blue_ = 0,
        alpha_ = 0.5;

std::vector<gazebo::math::Vector3> box_points_;

};
#endif
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18864/getboundingbox()-values-not-changing-after-scale-in-gazebo-(using-:-visual_plugin)/) by [JimmyHalimi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4840/jimmyhalimi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I also tried and maybe is something wrong with GetBoundingBox() and hope one day it will be fixed. GetScale() is working fine and its updating the scale factor so you can use this scale factor to get the right values for bounding box.

```
gazebo::math::Box box_scaled
box_scaled.min = ( box_->GetBoundingBox().min * box_->GetScale() ); 
box_scaled.max = ( box_->GetBoundingBox().max * box_->GetScale() );
```

then use this box_scaled to get the corner points

```
_buff.x = box_scaled.min.x; 
_buff.y = box_scaled.min.y; 
...
```

---

Originally posted by [fitimhalimi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5399/fitimhalimi/) with karma: 16 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JimmyHalimi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4840/jimmyhalimi/) on 2018-05-29**:
Just tried man, and it works, thank you very much